# How to detect an air-tap without having to point something with the cursor/pointer?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I’m making a HoloLens 2 app using Unity and MRTK, I need to instantiate a gameObject in the coordinates of the user hand when the user performs an Air-tap gesture, I was trying to achieve this using `IMixedRealityInputHandler`, but the problem is that in order to detect the air-tap gesture, the user need to be pointing towards the gameObject that has the script to implements that interface attached,

Any idea about how can I detect the air-tap mid-air without the need of pointing something directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To listens for input events and disregarding what GameObject in focus, you can create a component registered global input handlers, more information please see:[Register for global input events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/input/input-events#register-for-global-input-events)

Answer (score 1):

To provide a more specific answer, I've provided test code below. This is based on the answer by Hernando.

> ...you can create a component registered global input handlers, more
> information please see:[Register for global input events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/input/input-events#register-for-global-input-events)

```
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;
using UnityEngine;

public class AirTapper : MonoBehaviour, IMixedRealityGestureHandler
{
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // Instruct Input System that we would like to receive all input events of type IMixedRealityGestureHandler
        CoreServices.InputSystem?.RegisterHandler<IMixedRealityGestureHandler>(this);
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        // Instruct Input System to disregard all input events of type IMixedRealityGestureHandler
        CoreServices.InputSystem?.UnregisterHandler<IMixedRealityGestureHandler>(this);
    }
    
    public void OnGestureStarted(InputEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Gesture started: " + eventData.MixedRealityInputAction.Description);
    }
    
    public void OnGestureUpdated(InputEventData eventData)
    {
    }
    
    public void OnGestureCompleted(InputEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Gesture completed: " + eventData.MixedRealityInputAction.Description);
    }
    
    public void OnGestureCanceled(InputEventData eventData)
    {
    }
}
```